# UiAutomator inside Java Project

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, ui-automation

I'm currently writing a program crawling third party Android Apps for keywords.

I have a Maven Project and am trying to include the `uiautomator` library provided by Google. (like described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/packages.html)) There are some issues though. What I've done so far:

- Switched to gradle.
- Included the google maven repository.
- Added `androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'` to gradle dependencies.

IntelliJ then told me that it does not regconize `androidTestCompile` which I tried to fix copying code from all over the place, which obviously did not work.

I understand that UiAutomator is mainly used in Android App Programming (for example via Android Studio) for testing said Apps' UI, but I fail to see why it wouldn't be able to include needed libraries outside of that context.

So here are my questions:

- Can I include Googles `uiautomator` library inside a non-Android Maven project?
- If I have to switch to gradle, what are needed steps to get `androidTestCompile` to work?

Thanks in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: "Can I include Googles uiautomator library inside a non-Android Maven project?" -- AFAIK, no. "If I have to switch to gradle, what are needed steps to get androidTestCompile to work?" -- create an Android app project, presumably.